# Stats on every n rows for each column

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation for every nth (in my case every 6) rows (or samples). The following function gives me the means for every 6 rows (96 rows gives me 16 mean values)

```
colMeans(matrix(data.trim$X0, nrow=6))
```

I would like to do this for ALL columns (a total of 1280 mean values). I tried running this function:

```
colMeans(matrix(data.trim, nrow=6))
```

but this does not work at all and I get the following error message:

> Error in colMeans(matrix(data.trim, nrow = 6)) : 'x' must be numeric

In addition: Warning message:

> In matrix(data.trim, nrow = 6) : data length [80] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [6]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please provide sample data.  See [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the function to each column with `sapply`:

```
sapply(iris[1:4], function(x) colMeans(matrix(x, nrow=6)))
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
 [1,]     4.950000    3.383333     1.450000   0.2333333
 [2,]     4.850000    3.316667     1.483333   0.2000000
 [3,]     5.183333    3.633333     1.316667   0.2500000
```

...

```
[23,]     6.533333    2.950000     5.583333   1.9333333
[24,]     6.516667    3.033333     5.316667   2.1333333
[25,]     6.383333    3.033333     5.266667   2.1333333
```

Compare with creating the means of the first six rows manually:

```
colMeans(iris[1:6, 1:4])
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   4.9500000    3.3833333    1.4500000    0.2333333
```

You can also do this with `aggregate` given the proper `by` argument:

```
aggregate(iris[1:4], by=list((seq(nrow(iris))-1) %/% 6), FUN=mean)
   Group.1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1        0     4.950000    3.383333     1.450000   0.2333333
2        1     4.850000    3.316667     1.483333   0.2000000
3        2     5.183333    3.633333     1.316667   0.2500000
```

...

This works by creating a vector which identifies the groups to be averaged:

```
(seq(nrow(iris))-1) %/% 6
  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8
 [53]  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17
[105] 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24
```

The `sapply` solution returns a matrix, whereas the `aggregate` solution returns a data frame, in case one is more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible reason that you got `Error`, `warning` message is because you applied it directly on the `data.frame`.  For example

```
set.seed(48)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40, 80*96, replace=T), ncol=80))
rowMeans(matrix(d1, ncol=6, byrow=T))
#Error in rowMeans(matrix(d1, ncol = 6, byrow = T)) : 'x' must be numeric
#In addition: Warning message:
#In matrix(d1, ncol = 6, byrow = T) :
#  data length [80] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [14]
```

You could `unlist` the `data.frame`

```
 res <- rowMeans(matrix(unlist(d1), ncol=6, byrow=T))
 dim(res) <- c(96/6, 80)
length(res)
#[1] 1280
```

Crosschecking the results from @Matthew Lundberg's method

```
res1 <- sapply(d1, function(x) colMeans(matrix(x, nrow=6)))

all.equal(res,res1, check.attributes=F)
[1] TRUE
```