# Computing for each datafram column the mean of three subsequent row data for each row (R)

Tags: r, performance, sapply

First, simple R example for my problem:

```
> df
   x  y
1  1  3
2  2  7
3  4  9
4  8  0
5  3  1
6 12 24
```

I'd like to compute for each column the mean of three subsequent row data for each row, which results into the following dataframe.

```
> dfRes
      xRes     yRes
         x        y
1 2.333333 6.333333
2 4.666667 5.333333
3 5.000000 3.333333
4 7.666667 8.333333
5       NA       NA
6       NA       NA
```

Since I've got very big dataframe with many columns and rows, I'd like to avoid using a for loop for this computation. I've tried defining custom function to use the available `sapply` function.

Does somebody know an simple solution in R with a relative fast computation time for this problem?

---- Update ----
The calculation procedure should be something like:

```
xRes[1] = mean(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])
xRes[2] = mean(x[2] + x[3] + x[4])
...
xRes[5] = NA # because there is no x[7]
```

Comment: How exactly did you compute the results in the sample dataset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the mean of every 13 rows in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359427/calculate-the-mean-of-every-13-rows-in-data-frame)

Comment: How is the first value 3.5 or second value 14?

Comment: For example `x[1] + x[2] + x[3] = xRes[1]`, `x[2] + x[3] + x[4] = xRes[2]` etc.. For x[5] it isn't possible to calculate the mean, because we are missing the 7th row value. I'm updating my question to make this more clearly.

Comment: In general you can get the previous values in a column by lag(x, i) with i denoting how far back you go. So (lag(x) + lag(x,2) + lag(x,3))/3 will give you the mean you want. You don't even need to define a new function for this. Just use dplyr and use mutate across all columns.

Comment: That's right. There `dfRes` results were wrong. I have updated the question.

Comment: The function provided by Ronak Shah is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rolling functions with an appropriate window size.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, zoo::rollmean, 3, fill = NA, align = 'left')
```

---

If your data is huge using `data.table` might help.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, frollmean, 3, align = 'left')]
```

Answer (score 0):

how about map function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/map
its actually a really good alternative to for-loop

Answer (score 0):

I'd transform the data frame in a matrix and use colMeans with the nrow argument.
The solution is basically copied from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151007/7941188

```r
# devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")
foo <- read.so::read.so(
"
   x  y
1  1  3
2  2  7
3  4  9
4  8  0
5  3  1
6 12 24")

foo_mat <- as.matrix(foo)

sapply(foo, function(x) colMeans(matrix(x, nrow = 3)))
#>             x        y
#> [1,] 2.333333 6.333333
#> [2,] 7.666667 8.333333
```

This depends on length(matrix) being a multiple of (3). In the other post I linked to there is a solution which apparently deals with other cases

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` based on the method of [this historic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862334/6574038).

```
n <- 3
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) c(na.omit(filter(x, rep(1 / n, n))), rep(NA, n - 1)))
df1  
#          x        y
# 1 2.333333 6.333333
# 2 4.666667 5.333333
# 3 5.000000 3.333333
# 4 7.666667 8.333333
# 5       NA       NA
# 6       NA       NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(2.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 5, 7.66666666666667, 
NA, NA), y = c(6.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lag` , `lead` and `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
df%>%
mutate(x=(lag(x,0)+lead(x)+lead(x,2))/3 , y=(lag(y,0)+lead(y)+lead(y,2))/3)
```