# Averaging n-values in a 3d array in R

Tags: r

I have a 3D-array (x, y, z) and would like to average values, every n values, over only one of these dimensions, using R (the first or the third, depending on my calculations).

I have seen solutions such as this one: [Stats on every n rows for each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150892/stats-on-every-n-rows-for-each-column)
but do not seem to be able to implement it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
apply(ar1, 1, mean)
apply(ar1, 3, mean)
```

---

Or this may be more efficient with `rowMeans/colMeans` as mentioned by @user20650

```
rowMeans(ar1, dims=1)
colMeans(ar1, dims = 2)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
ar1 <- array(rnorm(5 * 3 *2), dim = c(5, 3, 2))
```

Comment: Sorry @akrun, I realised lately that "every n values" which is in the title was not in the main text of my question...

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `asplit` (but I believe [the answer by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67461790/12158757) is more efficient)

```
sapply(asplit(ar1, 1), mean)
```

Comment: Sorry @ThomasIsCoding, I realised lately that "every n values" which is in the title was not in the main text of my question...